# Is it true that $\frac 1q=\sum\limits_{\text{prime }p}^{\infty}\frac{1}{q^{p-1}-1}$ for all $q\notin[-1,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, q-series

I believe I have proved that, for all $q\notin[-1,1]$, it follows

> $$\frac{1}{q}=\sum_{\text{prime }p}^\infty\frac{1}{q^{p-1}-1}$$

Of course this is a huge result, so I want to see if my proof is valid.

---

For $|q|<1$, it follows that

$$\begin{align}\frac{q}{1-q}&=q+q^2+q^3+q^4+\cdots \\ \therefore \frac{q^2}{1-q^2}&=q^2+q^4+q^6+q^8+\cdots\end{align}$$ $$\therefore \frac{q}{1-q}-\frac{q^2}{1-q^2}=q+q^3+q^5+q^7+\cdots$$ We also have that: $$\frac{q^3}{1-q^3}=q^3+q^6+q^9+q^{12}+\cdots$$ $$\therefore \frac{q}{1-q}-\frac{q^2}{1-q^2}-\frac{q^3}{1-q^3}=q+q^5+q^7+q^{11}+\cdots$$ and if we keep subtracting $\cfrac{q^p}{1-q^p}$ for the next prime $p$, we will be left with $q$. $$\therefore \frac{q}{1-q}-\sum_{\text{prime }p}^{\infty}\frac{q^p}{1-q^p}=q$$ $$\therefore \frac{1}{1-q}=\sum_{\text{prime }p}^{\infty}\frac{q^{p-2}}{1-q^p}$$ Now let $q\mapsto \cfrac 1q$. Since our original constraint was $|q|<1$, then $q\mapsto \cfrac 1q$ implies $\bigg|\cfrac 1q\bigg|<1$, or, $q\notin[-1,1]$. $$\therefore \cfrac{1}{1-\frac 1q}=\sum_{\text{prime }p}^{\infty}\frac{1}{q^{p-2}\big(1-\frac{1}{q^p}\big)}$$ for any $q\notin[-1,1]$. Multiply both sides by $\cfrac{q-1}{q^2}$ and we have: $$\cfrac 1q=\sum_{\text{prime }p}^\infty\frac{1}{q^{p-1}-1}$$

---

Is this a valid proof? If so, has this result been discovered before?

Thanks.

Comment: I did a relatively quick check. One mistake is with your $\frac{q^3}{1 - q^3}$ expansion, there's a $q^6$ term which you didn't include in the subtraction. In general, there will be many other such terms with higher primes expansions. Also, going from the second last line to your last line, on the right side, the part being summed is $\frac{1}{q^{p-2}\left(1-\frac{1}{q^{p}}\right)} = \frac{1}{q^{p-2}\left(\frac{q^{p} - 1}{q^{p}}\right)} = \frac{q^2}{q^{p} - 1}$. Thus, multiplying by $\frac{q-1}{q^2}$ would give $\frac{q-1}{q^{p}-1}$, which is *not* the same as $\frac{1}{q^{p-1}-1}$.

Comment: Oh right, yeah idk why I did that. I originally wrote the formula as $\frac{1}{q(q-1)}=\sum \frac{1}{q^p-1}$ i must have lazily messed it up. Doesn't matter anyways because of the muck-up with the $q^3$ power series expansion. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\frac1{1-q^p}=\sum_{p\mid k}q^k$, so
$$ \sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{q^{p-2}}{1-q^p}=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\sum_{p\mid k+2}q^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k\sum_{p\mid k+2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\omega(k+2)q^k$$
and this is not the same as $\frac1{1-q}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k$.

Also, checking the claim itself for $q>1$, already the first of all positive summands is $\frac1{q-1} > \frac1q$.